# Google Play considering privacy policy invalid due to 404 error

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, privacy, privacy-policy

I have uploaded an app to Google Play however it has been flagged with the following error:

"Issue: Invalid privacy policy URL

We reviewed your app’s privacy policy provided and found it does not meet the policy requirements.

You must provide a valid URL link to your app’s privacy policy. The link must be maintained at all times while the app is available on Google Play, and it must link to a privacy policy that clearly and accurately describes your app’s data collection and use. Privacy policy is a requirement for all apps - even if your app does not collect any personal and sensitive user data."

I asked in an email for further details and I got the following message

"The link provided in the store listing information https://www.outgoingapp.net/privacy leads to an error message (404 error), which is not compliant with the Privacy Policy section of our User Data policy. Kindly resubmit your privacy policy without trailing slash (if any) or set up a redirection."

- Does anyone get a 404 error when oppening https://www.outgoingapp.net/privacy ? Every single device/browser I have tested works. If you get the error please provide me with a print screen of the error, the browser, and OS you are using, the detailed console error message.
- Do you know what do they mean by "resubmit your privacy policy without trailing slash (if any) or set up a redirection" since we only use three trailing slashes and all of them are essential and also, in my experience, the link https://www.outgoingapp.net/privacy/ is always openable.
- As anyone been through a similar situation? If so what did you do to solve it?
- Do you know why are they having problems opening the link but I am not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Link works for me, no 404.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you try to republish you app on the Play Store ?

Comment: No however I have noticed that even though the page opens when you open the console it shows the 404 error is actually there.

Comment: Link works for me too. And I have the same problem now. Did you solve it?